# I have two filesystem partitions. Now Ubuntu complains that one is full

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, filesystem, storage

I keep receiving a message after boot that says: Root filesystem only has XXXX MB left.

I've run `sudo fdisk -l` and I see this:

```
    Device    Size     Type
/dev/sda1     499MB    Windows recovery

/dev/sda2     100MB    EFI System

/dev/sda3     16M      Microsoft reserved

/dev/sda4     13,9GB   Linux filesystem

/dev/sda5     15,8GB   Microsoft Basic data

/dev/sda6     14,9GB   Linux swap

/dev/sda7     886,4GB  Linux Filesystem
```

When I open the disk management window, I see that Linux only refers to rootfs only as the 13,9GB part. Why is it not taking into consideration the other partition?

Comment: We don't know where you have those *file systems* mounted, but the "/" or *root* partition will be only one of them, possibly the other is /home used for data and not for system data.  `mount |grep sda` will show what where *fs* are mounted (or `lsblk` etc)    *FYI:  If 14GB is your / partition, that's small; 25GB is recommended for Ubuntu desktop (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) though my own usage would find 25GB too small; it'll depend on how you use your system*

Comment: I understand it is small, and I would like to allocate some space from sda7 to it. Is it possible to change this without having to reinstall Ubuntu? I already have a lot of work and configuring that I wouldn't like to use (It is my work computer ant not a PC).

Comment: Indeed, sda4 is /, sda7 is/ home, as shown by `mount | grep sda`

Comment: why do you have a swap partitition? Remove that and you get 15Gb  to play with. Use a swapfile. That is the default since a couple of years. In regards to the size of /: 15Gb is ENOUGH for a desktop. I would suggest to check /var/log/ for large log files and if there is ... fix the notice in it and then empty the log file If that is the cause adding Gb to sda4 is not a solution and will result in the same problem showing up a few days later

Comment: The logs folder doesn't amount to 300MB. I found usr/lib to be large though, with 3GB. However I am not aware of the normal sizes for each of these folders, so I cannot say for sure whether something is unusual or not.

Comment: 300Mb is nothing. You need to find something large like in the Gbs that is something personal (ie related to your machine your actions). `/usr/lib/` should not grow as it contents are static. Most of / is static on a desktop except for /var/ :)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that 300MB is little. What is growing inside var is /var/lib.

Comment: Do you have server software installed?  Like apache or mysql? Cuz mysql uses /var/lib and you really should change the mysql defaults to look at a dedicated(/private) partition for that. A database will run into several Gbs

Comment: DOCKER. That might be the one. Check the size of `/var/lib/docker/overlay` and `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` and can you do a `docker system prune --all --volumes --force` and you can also delete docker log files with `find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type f -name “*.log” -delete`

Comment: I only have a `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` and no overlay. It's size is 83kB though...

Answer (score 1):

To find out (from the command line) the size on any directory, use this 'disk usage' command:

```
cd /
sudo du -ch --one-file-system --max-depth=1 .
```

This will (after some time) produce a list of directories and the amount of diskspace each takes. Change directories into your first suspect and repeat:

```
cd /var # for example
sudo du -ch --one-file-system --max-depth=1 .
```

Keep at it until you find what fills up the system. For larger directories, use a variant: `sudo du --one-file-system --max-depth=1 . | sort -n`. Less legible, but it will show you the biggest last.

Should everything be OK but your root filesystem is getting too full (because you have installed too much stuff or you really need all those old log files or all those TTF fonts) AND IF your root filesystem (sda4) and swap (sda6) are adjacent, you could make it into one larger filesystem:

Boot a live USB version, select 'try Ubuntu' and open a terminal (through the menu or Ctrl-Alt-t). Type

```
lsblk
```

and figure out which is your harddisk (you may see a sda, but that could be your USB stick). I'll use 'X' for whatever you find here. Start the graphical partitioner:

```
sudo gparted /dev/sdX
```

(replace the 'X' with the letter of your HD in the live environment). Now, delete the swap partition and enlarge the root filesystem (you cannot alter a mounted filesystem - that's why we have to use the USB stick). Make sure you choose 'Partition->Resize/move' and expand the root filesystem to include the space where the swap space was.

At your next boot, you will get trouble over the now missing swap space. I'm not sure what will happen - you might have to enter your (administrator/user) passwd and fix the problem (in single user mode), or it may just boot. Either way: Edit /etc/fstab with you favorite editor:

```
nano /etc/fstab
vi /etc/fstab
```

Find the line that has the word 'swap' and put a hash (#) in front of the line. Continue into multi-user mode by logging out of the maintenance shell (exit, or control-D).

You will now have a system without swap. To start swapping to a regular file, follow instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Now, it would be a good idea to find the cause. A lot of software, big logs, huge /swapfile in the current install... If not fixed, the problem may return.

Comment: I have a 99% usage on / and a 7% usage on home, which seems to indicate that home is actually not residing in the root.

Comment: Does `df -v` actually say `7% /home` AND `echo $HOME` starts with `/home`? Did you install a bunch of software? What is the output of `sudo du -ch --one-file-system --max-depth=1 /`? Are sda4 and sda5 adjacent? `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: Yes, 7% for home and `echo $HOME` starts with `/home`. Your `sudo du` code seems weird, it prints some partitions and then stop (I didn't give it much time to run though). sda4 and 5 are not adjacent. After sda4, theres sda6 and then sda7; then comes sda5.

Comment: The `du` command should have given you directories, with the disk usage per directory. It would have told you which directory is the biggest and this community would be able to tell if that is too big.

Comment: But you're in luck: since sda4 and sda6 ARE adjacent you could make it one filesystem. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: I have 14G in my current root filesystem with a ton of software: full office, graphics editing, kodi, 4 extra language packs (en,fr,de,nl,sp)) but without a /swapfile. My root filesystem is 30G big.

Comment: again: 15Gb as root is more than enough for a DESKTOP system. I have in 20 years of linux never needed more than 12Gb (and that was with an mysql database included). Even 20Gb is overkill. There is something else wrong with @adriaans system that needs to be fixed otherwise even 100Gb is not enough: something is filling the disk and it will just take a bit longer to reach 100Gb.

Comment: @adriaan NONE of those use / to store data you create. *All the software you can install from the regular repositories is not even going to end up to more than 15Gb*

Comment: I do not have MySQL or anything. I use the computer basically for Docker and Yocto. Perhaps one of those is taking up space?

Comment: Sincerely, I prefer not to do the procedure you indicated (exclude the swap partition and enlarge the filesystem) because:
1 - It's not my computer and I wasn't the one who made the partitioning.
2 - From what you mentioned, doing this would only delay a problem that is inevitable, I prefer to correctly solve the problem once and for all.

Comment: I appreciate that you're careful with someone else's system. Maybe show 'us' the output of the `sudo du -ch --one-file-system --max-depth=1 /` command? @Rinzwind: I agree that something is filling @Mölp system and I guess it's the directory that makes the `du` slow...

Comment: I've found the problem with your command, Adriaan. It was indeed the docker in a folder `/data/docker`. It had a big cache of up to 3GB. I've deleted it and now the rootfs is fine.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Edited my answer to include my suggestion to chase the problem with `du`.